# Проблемы с proxy c#

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, proxy

Весьма давно решился на написание софта для создания ботнетов в соц сетях. Начиналось все с инстаграмма, но там меня вскоре забанили по айпи, и я как-то подугас. Через некоторое время решил переписать проект под vk.
И так, у меня есть метод авторизации. Тк я из Украины, протестировать авторизацию без прокси попросту не могу(да и доступ к многим клиентам одновременно с одного айпи не лучшая идея), вероятно в ней есть недочёты, но сейчас не об этом. Не понимаю почему, но с проксями просто не получаю html. Прокси использую свежие, стого http. Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace vkbot
{
    class VK : IDisposable
    {
        const string USER_AGENT =
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) " +
            "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
            "Chrome/45.0.2414.0 Safari/537.36";

        HttpClientHandler m_handler;
        HttpClient m_client;

        public VK()
        {
            m_handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            m_client = new HttpClient(m_handler);
            m_client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://vk.com/");
            m_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(USER_AGENT);
            m_handler.UseProxy = true;
            m_handler.Proxy = new WebProxy("89.175.129.145:55653");
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            m_client.Dispose();
            m_handler.Dispose();
        }
        async void GetCookie()
        {
            await m_client.GetAsync("/login/");
            //var cookies = m_handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(m_client.BaseAddress);
        }
        public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
        {
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(await m_client.GetAsync("/login").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            string ip_h = Convert.ToString(document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[13]").InnerHtml);
            var cookies = m_handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(m_client.BaseAddress);
            HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/login/");
            message.Headers.Host = "login.vk.com";
            message.Headers.Referrer = m_client.BaseAddress;
            Dictionary<string, string> fields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"_origin", Convert.ToString(m_client.BaseAddress)},
                {"act","login" },
                {"email",username},
                {"pass",password },
                {"role","al_frame" }
            };
            var responce = await m_client.SendAsync(message);
            return responce.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Прокси инициализировал в конструкторе, это временная мера если что.

PS сейчас прошу помочь с прокси, но если у вас есть что сказать по поводу остального кода - пишите. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Использование `.Result` убивает асинхронность. / Хорошо бы вызывать где нужно `Dispose()` или обернуть все в `using`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему вы не используете [библиотеки для работы с VK](https://www.google.com/search?q=vk%20net&rlz=1C1CHBD_ruRU833RU833&oq=vk%20net&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1247j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? Например, vkNet. И не надо ломать голову, почему ваш запрос не работает.

В более общем случае, берете [HTTP снифер](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=IgnBXMppktibBeeDk5AE&q=HTTP%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80&btnK=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%20Google&oq=HTTP%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i10i42j0i22i30l9.531.531..1098...0.0..0.88.159.2......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....0.3P3_K8b3dh0) и смотрите чем оригинальный запрос с из браузера, отличается от вашего.

Так же стоит сказать, что http-прокси - такое-себе. Возьмите Socks5. И обязательно, проверьте прокси через ProxyChecker.